# Javassist API with Junit

Tags: java, junit, javassist

I am attempting to change some third party class definitions, before each test, to simulate different results. I have to use something like javassist because extending the classes, sometimes, is just not possible due to the access modifiers. Here is an example of what I am attempting to do with javassist and junit combined:

```
public class SimulatedSession extends SomeThirdParty {

    private boolean isJoe = false;
    public SimulatedSession(final boolean isJoe) {
        this.isJoe = isJoe;
    }

    @Override
    public void performThis() {
        final ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        final CtClass internalClass = classPool.get("some.package.Class");
        final CtMethod callMethod = internalClass.getDeclaredMethod("doThis");
        if (isJoe) {
            callMethod.setBody("{System.out.println(\"Joe\");}");
        } else {
            callMethod.setBody("{System.out.println(\"mik\");}");
        }
        internalClass.toClass();
    }
}

@Test
public void firstTest() {
     SimulatedSession toUse = new SimulatedSession(false);
     // do something with this object and this flow
}

@Test
public void nextTest() {
     SimulatedSession toUse = new SimulatedSession(true);
     // do something with this object and this flow
}
```

if I run each test individually, I can run the code just fine. When I run them using the unit suite, one test after the other, I get a "frozen class issue". To get around this, I am looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20237241/5655414), however, I must admit I am unsure as to how one can use a different class pool to solve the issue.

Comment: your tests don't even compile, I guess you meant `new SimulatedSession(false).performThis();`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I meant it more of an example, but i updated the question so one can see what I am attempting to do. Calling perfomrThis method will be invoked, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will try to load twice the same class into the same `ClassLoader` which is forbidden, you can only load once a class for a given `ClassLoader`.

To make your unit tests pass, I had to:

1. Create my own temporary `ClassLoader` that will be able to load `some.package.Class` (that I replaced by `javassist.MyClass` for testing purpose) and that will be implemented in such way that it will first try to load the class from it before the parent's CL.
2. Set my own `ClassLoader` as context `ClassLoader`.
3. Change the code of `SimulatedSession#performThis()` to be able to get the class instance created by this method and to call `internalClass.defrost()` to prevent the "*frozen class issue*".
4. Invoke by reflection the method `doThis()` to make sure that I have different output by using the class instance returned by `SimulatedSession#performThis()` to make sure that the class used has been loaded with my `ClassLoader`.

So assuming that my class `javassist.MyClass` is:

```
package javassist;

public class MyClass {
    public void doThis() {

    }
}
```

The method `SimulatedSession#performThis()` with the modifications:

```
public Class<?> performThis() throws Exception {
    final ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    final CtClass internalClass = classPool.get("javassist.MyClass");
    // Prevent the "frozen class issue"
    internalClass.defrost();
    ...
    return internalClass.toClass();
}
```

The unit tests:

```
// The custom CL
private URLClassLoader cl;
// The previous context CL
private ClassLoader old;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    // Provide the URL corresponding to the folder that contains the class
    // `javassist.MyClass`
    this.cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("target/classes").toURI().toURL()}){
        protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)
            throws ClassNotFoundException {
            try {
                // Try to find the class for this CL
                return findClass(name);
            } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
                // Could not find the class so load it from the parent
                return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }
    };
    // Get the current context CL and store it into old
    this.old = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    // Set the custom CL as new context CL
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
}

@After
public void restore() throws Exception {
    // Restore the context CL
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(old);
    // Close the custom CL
    cl.close();
}


@Test
public void firstTest() throws Exception {
    SimulatedSession toUse = new SimulatedSession(false);
    Class<?> c = toUse.performThis();
    // Invoke doThis() by reflection
    Object o2 = c.newInstance();
    c.getMethod("doThis").invoke(o2);
}

@Test
public void nextTest() throws Exception {
    SimulatedSession toUse = new SimulatedSession(true);
    Class<?> c = toUse.performThis();
    // Invoke doThis() by reflection
    Object o2 = c.newInstance();
    c.getMethod("doThis").invoke(o2);
}
```

**Output:**

```
mik
Joe
```

Comment: nice one! an impressive solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [retransformer](https://github.com/nickman/retransformer). It's a Javassist based lib I wrote for running tests just like this. It's a bit more terse than using raw Javassist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another approach. We had a similar problem as we once mocked a dependency - we could not reset it. So we did the following: Before each test we replace the 'live' instance with our mock. After the tests, we restore the live instance. So I propose that you replace the modified instance of your third party code for each test.

```
@Before
public void setup()
{
    this.liveBeanImpl = (LiveBean) ReflectionTools.getFieldValue(this.beanToTest, "liveBean");
    ReflectionTools.setFieldValue(this.beanToTest, "liveBean", new TestStub());
}


@After
public void cleanup()
{
    ReflectionTools.setFieldValue(this.beanToTest, "liveBean", his.liveBeanImpl);
}
```

The setFieldValue looks like this:

```
public static void setFieldValue(Object instanceToModify, String fieldName, Object valueToSet)
{
    try
    {
        Field declaredFieldToSet = instanceToModify.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        declaredFieldToSet.setAccessible(true);
        declaredFieldToSet.set(instanceToModify, valueToSet);
        declaredFieldToSet.setAccessible(false);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        String className = exception.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String message = exception.getMessage();
        String errorFormat = "\n\t'%s' caught when setting value of field '%s': %s";
        String error = String.format(errorFormat, className, fieldName, message);
        Assert.fail(error);
    }
}
```

So maybe your tests will pass if you reset your implementation for each test. Do you get the idea?